# How to perform the Eclipse->Refactor->Rename function programmatically for Java source code?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I have thousands of java files in my Eclipse project. I need to rename these files all. I know  I can rename a class interactively in Eclipse, but there're too many classes, how to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: Read up on [JDT Refactoring](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Write one simple JAVA program which reads all the java files from the current workspace location. Use the Files API and the move command to rename each of the file.

[JAVA 7 Files API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

Comment: Not a replacement for `Retractor -> Rename` feature in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of renaming your files is always the same then using [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) could be a fast and easy solution.